# NodeJS - PGP encryption on top of gzip a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, openpgp, openpgp.js

File is generated successfully but when trying to open file, it is in invalid gzip format after decryption. Shows error unsupported format and failing to decompress.

```
zlib.gzip("Hello World", async (err, compressedData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error compressing data:', err);
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      const message = await openpgp.createMessage({ text: compressedData.toString() });
      const publicKeyObj = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyForEncryption });
      const encryptedData = await openpgp.encrypt({ message, encryptionKeys: publicKeyObj });
  
      // Save the compressed and encrypted data to a file
      fs.writeFile('/path_to_file/output.txt.gz.gpg', encryptedData, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error saving compressed data to file:', error);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Data compressed and saved to file successfully.');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error encrypting data:', error);
    }
  });
```

Tried using zlib and openpgp(5.9.0) modules. Expecting the end file to be in format `.txt.gz.gpg` and should be able to decrypt and decompress to see the text file output.txt with Hello World as text inside the file.

Comment: `compressedData` is most certainly binary data and `compressedData.toString()` will do nothing good to it. You have to use `openpgp.createMessage({binary: compressedData })`

Comment: Thank you @derpirscher !!
Tried with `openpgp.createMessage({binary: new Uint8Array(compressedData)})` it works.